# C - Printf will compile but not print anything after moving block of code to different function and probably ruining loop somehow

Tags: c

I'm trying to move this block of code that just prints some lines to a separate function but every time I do it doesn't print anything.
This works exactly how I want it to:

```
    {
         ReadFile(PayrollRead, *FirstName[i], *LastName[i], HourlyRate[i], TotalHours[i],
         DefEarn[i]);
         ControlCalc(HourlyRate[i], TotalHours[i], DefEarn[i], GrossPay[i],
                     FedTax[i], StateTax[i], SsiTax[i], RegHours[i], OvtHours[i],
                     NetPay[i]);                
        printf("%-9s,%-9s%5.2lf%10.2lf%11.2lf%10.2lf%9.2lf%10.2lf\n",LastName[i], 
            FirstName[i],HourlyRate[i], RegHours[i], GrossPay[i], FedTax[i], SsiTax[i], NetPay[i]);
        printf("%34.2lf%21.2lf%9.2lf", OvtHours[i], StateTax[i], DefEarn[i]);
        printf("\n\n");
         i++;
         j++;
    }while (i<5);
```

But everytime I change it to this it just doesn't print anything, crashes and exits.

```
o
    {    ReadFile(PayrollRead, *FirstName[i], *LastName[i], HourlyRate[i], TotalHours[i],
         DefEarn[i]);
         ControlCalc(HourlyRate[i], TotalHours[i], DefEarn[i], GrossPay[i],
                     FedTax[i], StateTax[i], SsiTax[i], RegHours[i], OvtHours[i],
                     NetPay[i]);                
         PrintResults(*LastName[i], *FirstName[i], HourlyRate[i], RegHours[i],
                      GrossPay[i], FedTax[i], SsiTax[i], NetPay[i], 
                      OvtHours[i], StateTax[i], DefEarn[i]);
         i++;
         j++;
    }while (i<5);
.
.
.
void PrintResults(char LastName, char FirstName, double HourlyRate, double RegHours,
                  double GrossPay, double FedTax, double SsiTax, double NetPay,
                  double OvtHours, double StateTax, double DefEarn)
{
        
        printf("%-9s,%-9s%5.2lf%10.2lf%11.2lf%10.2lf%9.2lf%10.2lf\n",LastName, 
        FirstName,HourlyRate, RegHours, GrossPay, FedTax, SsiTax, NetPay);
        printf("%34.2lf%21.2lf%9.2lf", OvtHours, StateTax, DefEarn);
        printf("\n\n");            
}
```

and if I add a statement to just print some random message in PrintResults it will actually print it, but only one time.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Whia is `i`? what is `j`? why do you increment them both?

Comment: i is just to run that loop and I used to need j later in the program to print a different summary of the information I get. j is totally unnecessary I just forgot to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

The format is string, but given parameter is char.

Fix to print string:

**Do-while Block**

```
PrintResults(LastName[i], FirstName[i], HourlyRate[i], RegHours[i],
    GrossPay[i], FedTax[i], SsiTax[i], NetPay[i], 
    OvtHours[i], StateTax[i], DefEarn[i]);
```

**PrintResults signature**

```
void PrintResults(char* LastName, char* FirstName, double HourlyRate, double RegHours,
                  double GrossPay, double FedTax, double SsiTax, double NetPay,
                  double OvtHours, double StateTax, double DefEarn)
```

Comment: also, it's suspicious ReadFile(PayrollRead, *FirstName[i], *LastName[i], HourlyRate[i], TotalHours[i], DefEarn[i]), but I don't know definition.

Comment: A good compiler will warn about the `printf` format mismatch if you enable warnings, e.g. `gcc -Wall` does.

Comment: Thanks for the response! FirstName and Lastname are character arrays if it makes a difference. It won't compile with "char* LastName.."

Comment: @HamSalmon First and LastName have to be array of char array. could you fix it?

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot I fixed it exactly way you said I just forgot to add one of the stars the first time. Thanks a lot you're a life saver!!